# Is there a way to use Float16 on both iOS 13 and iOS14

Tags: ios, swift

From iOS 14, it provides `Float16`, but I have my own `Float16` [code](https://gist.github.com/codelynx/eeaeeda00828568aaf577c0341964c38).  I like to use either Apple's Float16 or my Float16 or both, on both iOS 13 and iOS 14.

I know @available is not suitable for switching Apple's Float16 and my Float16.  Also if #available(iOS 14, *) is not working for stored properties.  Or, if there is a way to disable or hide Apple's Float16 from Xcode project, then official Float16 will not interfer my Float16.

If you have an idea how to make this situation work around, I would like to hear that.  The bottom line I can rename all `Float16` to something like `MyFloat16` but I am expected that there is a a bit better way.

Thanks

Comment: **"Or, if there is a way to disable or hide Apple's Float16 from Xcode project, then official Float16 will not interfer my Float16"**. I don't know what you mean by interfer. If you have a `Float16` struct declared in your project you would need to refer to Apple's Float (you meant Swift) you will need to refer to it as `Swift.Float16`